# Folder path of a PowerShell file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell script file is located in `C:/this-folder/that-folder/another-folder/powershell-file.ps1`.

How do I get a variable that returns `C:/this-folder/that-folder/another-folder/`?

Comment: This _seems_ to be asking how `powershell-file.ps1` can get the parent directory path of _itself_, but it would be good to make that explicit.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this command in your script:

```
Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Answer (score 18):

In PowerShell 3.0 you can get it with the new `$PSScriptRoot` variable, and with `$PSCommandPath` you can get the full script path.

There's also a great post by MVP Keith hill you may want
to check: *[Determining $ScriptDir Safely](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/determining-scriptdir-safely/)*

Answer (score 12):

You can use a standard .NET method:

```
$dirName = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName("c:\temp\abc\myproj1\newdata.txt")
```

From *[PowerShell: Get parent directory name from file or directory path](http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-get-parent-directory-name-from-file-or-directory-path/2595)*.

Comment: The question isn't explicit but seems to be asking how to get the directory path of the _executing script_.  If you're going to hard-code paths you might as well just do `$dirName = "c:\temp\abc\myproj1"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to know what folder your script is running in when it's being run.

This should do it:

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Comment: This includes the script name, which is what he already knows, so the other answers are more correct.