# How to get the current file location in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am wondering how to get the location of the script I am running or writing. We have a set of .NET assemblies placed in the same directory as the current PowerShell script, and we want load them from the script. Right now I am using a fixed path to locate assemblies, but we want to load them from the current file location.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom
("C:\Work\Scripts\Assemblies\DynamicOps.ManagementModel.Client.dll")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom
("C:\Work\Scripts\Assemblies\DynamicOps.Repository.dll")
```

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063964/folder-path-of-powershell-file-in-powershell/9064015#9064015

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$MyInvocation
```

Contains an object with information about the current command, such as a script, function, or script block. You can use the information in the object, such as the path and file name of the script 
(`$myinvocation.mycommand.path`) or the name of a function (`$myinvocation.mycommand.name`) to identify the current command. This is particularly useful for finding the name of the script that is running. You'll get full help on automatic varible with [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347675.aspx) :

```
get-help about_Automatic_Variables -full
```

---

(Edited)
To get current directory you've got the CmdLet `Get-Location`

Comment: thanks JPBlanc! I tried with split-Path and it worked. $currentFileLocation = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Comment: I moved $currentFileLocation = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path line of code to function and it does not work.
It throws an error while running a script , any suggestions?
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Work\Scripts\GetVirtualMachineProvisiongGroup.ps1
Write-Error : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: ``$MyInvocation`` is an automatic variable.  If you write a function to do this, you need to grab the ``$MyInvocation`` from the parent scope.  Read this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/06/19/get-scriptdirectory.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` maybe?